# How to create a plot with several different aggregations in dropdowns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to create plot in plotly where there will be several dropdowns
1/ dropdown menu where I can select datetime xaxis granularity (day, week, month)
2/ dropdown menu where I can select "Country"

Dropdowns should work together and aggregations should be done in dropdowns.

What I have done is made aggregation dataframes, but I do not think it is the right way.
Somehow grouping could be done within dropdown buttons and number of buttons (+labels) added should be equal to number of "Countries" and their labels.

Thank a lot for helping. Couldn't find any information in Google.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(table_rows)
dfw = df.groupby(["wk"]).agg({'regs_cnt':'sum','fmsg_cnt':'sum','fpmnt_cnt':'sum'}).reset_index()
dfm = df.groupby(["mnth"]).agg({'regs_cnt':'sum','fmsg_cnt':'sum','fpmnt_cnt':'sum'}).reset_index()
x=df.dt
y=df.regs_cnt
y1=df.fmsg_cnt
y2=df.fpmnt_cnt
xw=dfw.wk
yw=dfw.regs_cnt
yw1=dfw.fmsg_cnt
yw2=dfw.fpmnt_cnt
xm=dfm.mnth
ym=dfm.regs_cnt
ym1=dfm.fmsg_cnt
ym2=dfm.fpmnt_cnt

buttons.append(dict(method='restyle',
                        label="Days",
                        visible=True,
                        args=[{'y':[y,y1,y2],
                               'x':[x],
                               'type':'scatter'}]
                        )
                  )
buttons.append(dict(method='restyle',
                        label="Weeks",
                        visible=True,
                        args=[{'y':[yw,yw1,yw2],
                               'x':[xw],
                               'type':'scatter'}]
                        )
                  )
buttons.append(dict(method='restyle',
                        label="Months",
                        visible=True,
                        args=[{'y':[ym,ym1,ym2],
                               'x':[xm],
                               'type':'scatter'}]
                        )
                  )
```

Comment: Consider formatting your question. See [markdown guide](https://www.markdownguide.org/) for more information

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve). In particular share (at least)  a sample of your original dataframe.